# Not getting inside getView() of BaseAdapter class

Tags: android

My code is as follows.The problem is that `getView()` method is not being called for once I checked my log for this

My fragment class is

```
public class AlertListFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    public ArrayList<AlertModel> mModelLIst=new ArrayList<AlertModel>();
    public AlertAdapter adapter;
    ListView mAlertList;
    CommentsDataSource datasource;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert_list, container, false);
         mAlertList=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.alertlist);

        System.out.println("details in fragment");
        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(getActivity());
        datasource.open();
        ArrayList<AlertModel> source = datasource
                .getAllContacts();

        if (source.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("response number of items"
                    + source.size());

            adapter = new AlertAdapter(getActivity(), source,getActivity().getResources());
            mAlertList.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert_list, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }
}
```

my adapter class is

```
public class AlertAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    ArrayList<String> btnpositions = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Resources res;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ViewHolder holder;
    AlertModel tempValue = null;

    public AlertAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList data, Resources res) {

        System.out.println("response number of items inside adapter view: ");
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        this.res = res;

    }




    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView msubject, mbody;
        public ImageView mTYpe;

        public LinearLayout mTYpeLay;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {


   System.out.println("response number of items inside adapter count: "+data.size());
        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;

        System.out.println("response number of items inside adapter count: "+data.size());
        return data.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View vis, ViewGroup arg2) {


        System.out.println("response number of items inside adapter view: "+arg0);
        View vi = vis;

        int crntposition = arg0;
        Context context;

        if (vis == null) {


            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_list_item, null);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.msubject = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsubject);
        holder.mbody = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtbody);
        holder.mTYpe = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgtype);
        holder.mTYpeLay=(LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.typelay);

        if (data.size() <= 0) {
            holder.msubject.setText("No Data");

        } else {
            vi.setTag(holder);
            vi.setTag(R.id.txtsubject, holder.msubject);
            vi.setTag(R.id.txtbody, holder.mbody);
            vi.setTag(R.id.imgtype, holder.mTYpe);

            holder.msubject.setTag(crntposition);
            holder.mbody.setTag(crntposition);
            holder.mTYpe.setTag(crntposition);


            tempValue = null;
            tempValue = (AlertModel) data.get(crntposition);


            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

            context = arg2.getContext();

            holder.msubject.setText(tempValue.getmMessage());
            if(tempValue.getmMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                holder.mTYpeLay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.quote_blue);
                holder.mTYpe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q);
            }
            else if(tempValue.getmMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
            {
                holder.mTYpeLay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.event_yellow);
                holder.mTYpe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.e);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.mTYpeLay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.wishes_red);
                holder.mTYpe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bday);
            }




        }

      vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(crntposition));

        return vi;

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.e("click","yess");

    }
    private class OnItemClickListener  implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position) {

            mPosition = position;



            System.out.println("pos"+mPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {



        }

    }

}
```

my xml file for the fragment is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="fencer.geo.ti.geofencer.fragments.AlertListFragment">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="fragment"
        android:id="@+id/txtt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/txtt"
        android:background="@color/second_grey"
       android:id="@+id/alertlist"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my log

```
05-14 15:10:04.362  13684-13684/fencer.geo.ti.geofencer I/System.out﹕ response number of items13

05-14 15:10:04.363  13684-13684/fencer.geo.ti.geofencer I/System.out﹕ response number of items inside adapter view:

05-14 15:10:04.363  13684-13684/fencer.geo.ti.geofencer I/System.out﹕ response number of items inside adapter count: 13

05-14 15:10:04.363  13684-13684/fencer.geo.ti.geofencer I/System.out﹕ response number of items inside adapter count: 13

05-14 15:10:04.363  13684-13684/fencer.geo.ti.geofencer I/System.out﹕ response number of items inside adapter count: 13
```

and my output is

[image: my output]

Comment: check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338281/custom-adapter-getview-method-is-not-called/16338380#16338380

Comment: @Blackbelt please check my full code I've edited it I havn't made any mistakes you mentioned in your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to wrong return in you `onCreateView`, with

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert_list, container, false);
```

you are returning a completely new inflated view, which ListView, has completely no knowledge of you adapter. Change it to

```
return view;
```