# Image not showing in picasso because gridview

Tags: android, picasso

the image is not showing , the app is launching but no image is dispalying , can you help me to fix that ? I guess problem with gridimage. plesae not that the place holder of picasso is not showing in the list view.

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridImages> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<GridImages> mGridImages = new ArrayList<GridImages>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<GridImages> mGridImages) {
        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGridImages);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mGridImages = mGridImages;
    }


    /**
     * Updates grid data and refresh grid items.
     * @param mGridData
     */
    public void setGridData(ArrayList<GridImages> mGridImages) {
        this.mGridImages = mGridImages;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = null;
if (convertView == null){

       LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
       convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
}
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

String url = "http://www.justedhak.comlu.com/images/uploaded_images.jpg";

Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .noFade().resize(150,150)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(holder.imageView);
return convertView;
}

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
    }
```

this is main activity.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
GridViewAdapter mGridAdapter;
private ArrayList<GridImages> mGridImages;
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    mGridImages = new ArrayList<>();

    mGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, mGridImages);
    listView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);


}
```

activity main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.justedhak.MainActivity" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>  


</RelativeLayout>
```

grid item layout

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
      />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338281/custom-adapter-getview-method-is-not-called/16338380#16338380)

Comment: @Blackbelt ill check it now thanks

Comment: @Blackbelt I read your answer but still i didnt find the problem

Comment: `mGridImages` is empty.

Comment: @Blackbelt you were right , so I post this question can you help me with it please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811785/concept-of-grid-list-view-how-to-send-image-to-imageitem-class

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout once. 
try to put the specific height for image view and see.

If you didn't succeed add you layout code.

Comment: I have edit my question chek it please