# concept of grid/list view how to send image to imageitem class

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

In my project I want to load url Images and display them in gridview activity. but how to load those image to the gridview adapter?

so I am trying to understand the concept of `grid/list view` adapter and as I understand .in a basic example ,it contain 3 activities:

**1-Main activity**

Useally it contains the definition of `gridview` layout , the definition of the method `GridViewAdapter` (third activity) ,setting the adapter in the grid view. and the data or the array image(second activity) that to be send in the `GridViewAdapter` method.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    }
```

ok my problem is what are the ways to send the image in the gridview adapter?

in this [example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) they used this way , but I dont need TypedArray for my project , actually side question when do I need to use it ?

```
  private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }
```

in another [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20141009125009/http://www.perfectapk.com/android-gridview-viewholder.html) they used resource

```
mItems = new ArrayList<GridViewItem>();
Resources resources = getResources();

mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.aim), getString(R.string.aim)));
:
mItems.add(new GridViewItem(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.youtube), getString(R.string.youtube)));
```

in another [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210919165842/https://caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html) they used static images

**Ok I do understand they are getting the image from drawable , but what should I do to display them in my activity**

-- Ill continue my explanation incase there is something wrong I did

**2-Imageitem** its the another activity where it store the image no need to go into it .

**3-GridViewAdapter**

ok here we create the constructor of the class , and we create the getview method , before getting into it , should I add `getcount()` method or `getitem()`
The convertview is used to get the old view, and the holder to hold the image I guess.
ofcourse for now `ImageItem` is empty because I didnt define it in the main activity. so how to do that ?

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        ImageItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());


    Picasso.
    with(mContext).
    load(ImageItem .Getimage())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher) 
     .fit() 
    .into(holder.imageView);

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

edt

```
//Downloading data asynchronously
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        Integer result = 0;
        try {
            // Create Apache HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(params[0]));
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            // 200 represents HTTP OK
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                String response = streamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
                parseResult(response);
                result = 1; // Successful
            } else {
                result = 0; //"Failed
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // Download complete. Let us update UI
        if (result == 1) {
            mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridImages);
            mGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Connection found,Check your Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String line;
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }

    // Close stream
    if (null != stream) {
        stream.close();
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Parsing the feed results and get the list
 * @param result
 */
private void parseResult(String result) {
    try {
        
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("result");
        GridImages item;
        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            String title = post.optString("name");
            String image=post.optString("path");
            item = new GridImages();
            item.Settitle(title);
            item.Setimage(image);
         //   JSONArray attachments = post.getJSONArray("attachments");
           // if (null != attachments && attachments.length() > 0) {
             //   JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
               // if (attachment != null)
                 //   item.Setimage(attachment.getString("url"));
            //}
            mGridImages.add(item);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: One should not use bitmap hard refrenced in object. You seem new to android. You can pass image url in ImageItem creating image url or id field. Now if images are from local resources you don't need picasso.

Comment: @subhash the above are just example , I am passing the iamge as url and I already stored the url in database but my problem if you can help me how to create a method that get the url from  database and send to the picasso . I created such method but didnt work

Comment: So the problem is retriving url's from sqlite, creating ImageItem objects and passing them as array in adapter?

Comment: @subhash no i am using mysql , with asynctask , what I am doing is uploadign an image to server and store its url to database mysql , then in my mainactivity I am displayin the image as gridview. so I ma having trouble how to get this url and call them in the adapter

Comment: ok so where in following process you  had problem?  1) Fetching data from server and creating list of ImageItem objects 2) Passing data to adapter 3) Consumption of data in adapter i.e displaying data

Comment: @subhash well I was able to fetch the url from php with asynctask , but I had problem to send them to the adapter and display the image correctly .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90799/discussion-between-subhash-and-moudiz).

Comment: @subhash please proceed I am waiting for you

Answer (score 1):

You Should not use bitmap inside the adapter because when it is in listview or gridview it will consume lot of memory which listview cannot recycle at once. So try using picasso to load the bitmap or image from url.