# Baseadapter getCount called but not getview

Tags: java, android, carousel

Am having this weird issue of getview not called inside baseadapter.

Scenario:

- Main fragment has a carousel (which loads perfectly fine)
- Button click shows another fragment with another carousel
- Data is fetched from server and the adapter is called
- Adapter gets called without a problem
- GetCount() gets called
- **GetView() does'nt get called**

---

> Interestingly the getView method is fired when the fragment is popped
>   or back button is pressed.

---

Adapter code

```
public class VideCarouselAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private NavigationFragment nf;
    private float scale;

    ArrayList<DataModel> videoList = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
    public VideCarouselAdapter(Context context,NavigationFragment nf) {
        this.context = context;
        this.nf=nf;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<DataModel> videoList) {
        Timber.log(Log.DEBUG,"VideCarouselAdapter instantiated");
        System.out.println(videoList);
        this.videoList=videoList;
        System.out.println("Total items"+videoList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return videoList.get(position);
        //return VideosCarouselItem.newInstance(context, position, scale,videoList.get(position).getVideoID());
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        Timber.log(Log.DEBUG,"VideCarouselAdapter GEtView");
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_coverflow, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.image = (SimpleDraweeView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+videoList.get(position).getVideoID()+"/0.jpg");
        Timber.log(Log.DEBUG, "SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL "+"http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+videoList.get(position).getVideoID()+"/0.jpg");
        holder.image.setImageURI(uri);
        holder.text.setText(videoList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Timber.log(Log.DEBUG,"Image touched "+parent.getClass().toString());
                CoverFlowCarousel coverflow=((CoverFlowCarousel)parent);
                int currentSelection=coverflow.getSelection();
                if(currentSelection==position) {
                    nf.presentFragment(VideoInformation.newInstance(videoList.get(position).getVideoID(),videoList.get(position).getTitle(),
                            videoList.get(position).getDescription()));
                    return;
                };
                if(currentSelection<position){
                    coverflow.fling(Math.round(coverflow.getX()+1200),Math.round(coverflow.getY()));
                }else{
                    coverflow.fling(Math.round(coverflow.getX()-1200),Math.round(coverflow.getY()));
                }


            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        Timber.log(Log.DEBUG,"VideCarouselAdapter COunt "+videoList.size());
        return videoList.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public SimpleDraweeView image;
    }


}
```

Debug log when fragment is on screen

```
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 12
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 12
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 12
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 12
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 12
```

Debug log the moment fragment is dismissed

```
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/kJQqJgGpfeQ/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/H403Uyf_TC0/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/78x8iOdUdXg/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/Pi7NhJE7O_0/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/MMg1TpADGBw/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter COunt 15
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/j3PwwoTjpNg/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/jB_zCJ2s2jc/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/SrldmVxWu_s/0.jpg
VideCarouselAdapter GEtView
SETTING IMAGE FOR RELATED CAROUSEL http://img.youtube.com/vi/ytka9QZoNAw/0.jpg
```

The current carousel creation code inside the sub fragment

```
private void setupCoverflow(){
    Timber.log(Log.DEBUG,"SETTING UP RELATED VIDEOS");
    carousel.setSpacing(0.55f);
    carousel.setScaleX(1.5f);
    carousel.setRotation(0.0f);
    adapter = new VideCarouselAdapter(getActivity(),this);
    adapter.setData(videoList);
    carousel.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(carouselCurrentItem==0)
        carousel.setSelection(adapter.getCount()/2);
    else
        carousel.setSelection(carouselCurrentItem);
    txtVideoTitle.setText(videoList.get(carousel.getSelection()).getTitle());


    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Carousel.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(View child, int position) {
            txtVideoTitle.setText(videoList.get(position).getTitle());
            carouselCurrentItem=position;
        }
    });

}
```

Mainfragment (Working carousel)
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/_7J6d3winzVWXf8eiAYqxe4jdbH5efcZ8QVU3HGZSEA

Subfragment (Similar code, but carousel does'nt work)
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/p12bBck2bDWWFGiHqaZwWe4jdbH5efcZ8QVU3HGZSEA

The red color, shows that carousel view is visible.
As i mentioned in the post, data is loaded, getcount events are called with the correct count.

Comment: After `adapter.setData(videoList);` you must call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to update the adapter.

Comment: Its still the same Dhaval, in fact i have tried that even before posting the question.

Comment: change the statement of inflating in getview like this: rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_coverflow, parent,false);

Comment: not sure but one effort of `notifyDataSetChanged` is that `getView()` mustn´t be called to refresh, isn´t it?

Comment: @akhilRao - there is no such method to inflate to accept boolean?
Opiatefuchs - In my main fragment, i was never called notifydatasetchanged. For the sub fragment, am only trying the possibilities

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338281/custom-adapter-getview-method-is-not-called) might be help you

Comment: @Sam, i have seen it before posting here. I have checked all possiblities. The same adapter works for the main fragment. Added screenshots

Comment: Put your log statement in condition "rowView == null" in your getView Method and see what happenes

Comment: Have you tried `carousel.postInvalidate()` after doing `carousel.setAdapter(adapter); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` ?

Comment: Doesn't help shark. Slowlearner, GetView() is not even getting called until the fragment is popped

Comment: Any updates on this thread ? I am facing a similar problem..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 adapter = new VideCarouselAdapter(getActivity(),this);
            adapter.setData(videoList);
YOUR_LISTVIEW.setAdapter(adapter);
```