# getCount overriden method doesnt called but constructor called

Tags: android

`MyAdapter` class extend from `BaseAdapter` but `MyAdapter` constructer called but `getCount` and `getView` method doesn't call

[image: Image description]

Comment: what is the size of arraylist ?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338380/2595870) should be helpful.

Comment: you forget this, modify your code.
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (poll_list.get(position));
    }

Comment: Please incorporate the referred code as text in your question.

Comment: list is the jsonArray ....hemant

Comment: ohhh git it ...

Comment: i forget list.notifychangelistener

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code, getCount() and getView are the overridden methods of BaseAdapter and whenever you create an object of **MyAdapter()** class the constructor will be called not the overridden methods, this where **polymorphism** works. getCount() and getView() will only serve to the class,so when the adapter is sets up only then they will return the values.