# getView and getItem in BaseAdapter are never called

Tags: android, kotlin

First it said that my listView is null. Fixed this. Then i debuged the Adapter and i found out that the getView and getItem are never called.

Here is my Adapter:

```
class PropertiesAdapter(private val context: Context, private val properties: ArrayList<Property>) : BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        Log.d("getCount", "${properties.size}")
        return properties.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        Log.d("getItem", "${properties[position]}")
        return properties[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        Log.d("getItemId", "${position.toLong()}")
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        Log.d("getView", "$properties")
        val property = properties[position]
        val layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.property, null)

        myView.title.text = property.title
        myView.descr.text = property.descr
        myView.location.text = property.location
        myView.price.text = property.price

        return myView
    }
}
```

Here is my Log:

```
D/getCount: 3
D/getCount: 3
D/getItemId: 0
D/getItemId: 0
```

Comment: Please share your base adapter and Logs set your functions names , what is the 3 or 0?!!1

Comment: My adapter is here and the Log is now edited.

Comment: BASE ADAPTER not adapter , share your base adapter that your inherit from it and show your Logs as it

Comment: I inherit from the base adapter in andorid. It's not my custom.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338281/custom-adapter-getview-method-is-not-called You can see the checklist in topic, It may helpful for you

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i already found the error. It was were the adapter was set to the list.